# JavaScript Not Removing Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a JavaScript class so when link is clicked that has a class of parent it will remove it and then add a class of .open

I have got addClass working **but is not removing parent class when click on**.

**And when clicked closed should remove class open and revert it back to parent.**

**JavaScript Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.parent').on('click', function() {
        $('.parent').addClass('.open').removeClass('.parent');
    });
</script>
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="site-container">
<header id="header">

</header>

<div id="column_left" class="active">
<nav id="menu">
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/dashboard');?>"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>

<li><a class="parent" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#setting"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> <span>System</span></a>
    <ul id="setting" class="nav collapse">
        <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#user">Users</a>
            <ul id="user" class="nav collapse">
                <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Group</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>

<div class="page-container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Dashboard <small>Dashboard Stats</small></h1>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The whole idea is to toggle classes "parent" and "open" on link click.
- Because of dynamical element classes it should be `$(static_selector).on('click', '.parent,.open'`.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/27vuskLc/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on('click', '.parent,.open', function()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass("parent open");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add the period in [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/):

Replace:

```
$('.parent').addClass('.open').removeClass('.parent');
```

With:

```
$('.parent').addClass('open').removeClass('parent');
```

Also, it's more efficient to use `$(this)` instead of `$('.parent')` in the event listener, since `this` is the target of the click event. jQuery won't have to look for `.parent`, then.

Comment: And just to mention: it will be more logical to use `$(this)` instead of `$('.parent')` inside click event handler.

Comment: True, that. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Well, it's not only about efficiency. If there are more than one `.parent` on page, original code will result in adding `.open` to all `.parent` elements, not only to the clicked one.

Comment: Is there away also to revert back to parent if link is closed?

Comment: @Regent Some thing like this `<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.parent').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('open').removeClass('parent');

  // If link is closed 
  $(this).addClass('parent').removeClass('open');
 });
</script>`

Comment: @acoderslife take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27vuskLc/) to see how it can be done.

Comment: @Regent It works can you make that as a answer it works.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.parent').on('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('open').removeClass('parent');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to apply . as class when you add or remove class, [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/3k30a1wx/)

```
$('.parent').on('click', function() {
        $('.parent').addClass('open').removeClass('parent');
});
```